# Why do some Constructors with parameter still call this()? It seems to not do anything?

Tags: java, constructor, linked-list

The following code comes from `LinkedList.java` in `1.8` version.
I can't understand why `this()` is called? The constructor `LinkedList()` seems to do nothing?

```
/**
 * Constructs an empty list.
 */
public LinkedList() {
}

/**
 * Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified
 * collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's
 * iterator.
 *
 * @param  c the collection whose elements are to be placed into this list
 * @throws NullPointerException if the specified collection is null
 */
public LinkedList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    this();
    addAll(c);
}
```

Comment: that just calls the default constructor

Comment: Where do you instantiate the class?

Comment: Only speculation, but I could imagine it is a provision for future versions. Maybe someday the default ctor will "do something". Then you already have the parametered ctor fixed along with it.

Comment: Thank you all ,I think I solve my confusion.

Comment: Or possibly it >did< something in the past and removing it might break something.  (I can't imagine what though ...)

Comment: Indeed, in the Java 6 source, the `LinkedList` constructor body is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. It does nothing. Empty constructor calls `super()` by default. Without `this()` second constructor will also call `super()` by default. My guess is once there was some initialisation  in `LinkedList()` and by calling `this()`, this initialisation is also used in `LinkedList(Collection<? extends E> c)`.  And now it is a useless and harmless leftover.

Answer (score 0):

We can't give you a definitive reason why they call an empty constructor.

But if you look at the same class in Java 6, you will see that *there* the no-args constructor is defined like this:

```
public LinkedList() {
    header.next = header.previous = header;
}
```

So my theory is that the reason for the call to `this()` rather than `super()` in Java 8 is:

- either there is no reason: it is simply an oversight,
- the `this()` call was it was kept for compatibility reasons<sup>1</sup>.

In practice this should not have any performance impact.  The JIT compiler should be able to inline the redundant constructor call.

---

<sup>1 - For example, removing a constructor stack frame from the call chain could conceivably cause someone's custom `SecurityManager` code to break. Security check logic may depend on counting stack frames between as call from untrusted code and the code doing the check.</sup>